# How to update on doctrine's persist method by custom field

Tags: php, doctrine

Good morning,

normally on `$em->persist($variable)` doctrine checks the id field if the entry exist. In my case, i get the entries to insert/update from a file where a id, named `òld_id` by example. This id is stored in my Database.

Now i try to update the db entries where doctrine should compare the `old_id` field from database and file.

Is this possible?

I could fetch all database entries before persist() and compare myself. But if is there a better solution, maybe to set a custom id field i would try this.

Comment: Why is there an old ID? Is there a new ID for the same entity? Are you copying or moving entities?

Comment: its only an example. i called it old_id because its the old_id from the file which was a string. Now, in the database the id field is an integer autoincrement,